# How can I index these queries?

Tags: mysql

I am a little confused about the indexing I am going to do.

First, I am using a 4-column index, like this:

Index Name - advanced_query

Columns will be used in the index - title, category 1, category 2, category 3

The Indexing Code

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX advanced_query (`title`, `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3`, `date_posted`)
```

Okay, so this is how (from what I understand) it will work:

- a query of **title** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_3** will **NOT** use the index. So I will create a different index for it.
- a query of **title, cat_1** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_3** will use the index.

**TL;DR**

So in this index, only a **query of cat_3** will not benefit from it, right? Thanks!

**Q/A**

What query am I doing ? searching a post (it's title and 3 different categories)

What is the size of table ? Less than 2 thousand rows

Structure of the table ?

```
CREATE TABLE `post_lists` (
 `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `users_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `details` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
 `cat_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `date_posted` (`date_posted`),
 KEY `code` (`urlcode`),
 KEY `users_id_date_posted` (`users_id`,`date_posted`),
 KEY `title_date_posted` (`title`,`date_posted`),
 KEY `cat_1_date_posted` (`cat_1`,`date_posted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How many times will this table use ? Most of the time. This is the **advanced search** function so not just frequently as the **basic search** is.

This is how I actually will use the index.

Example Table

```
title | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | date_posted
```

My queries are simple:

1. **title**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
2. **title** + **cat_1**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
3. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_2**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
4. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
5. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' and cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
6. **title** + **cat_2**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
7. **title** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
8. **title** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
9. **cat_1**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
10. **cat_1** + **cat_2**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
11. **cat_1** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
12. **cat_1** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
13. **cat_2**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
14. **cat_2** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
15. **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`

How can I query this?

**Edit**

Hi, I read and searched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted DESC`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?

Comment: To find out if your queries use your indexes, you should run each of them after adding `EXPLAIN` to the start of them, so `EXPLAIN SELECT * ...` Maybe add the output of the explains to your question Also, please note that indexes won't work for the title if you use a wildcard at the start, so `'%title%'` won't use an index but `'title'` and `'titl%'` will.

Comment: @FMashiro I see, so instead of double `%` I will use one '%'? Thanks.

Comment: Also, when users ask for `Structure of the table ? ` they usually mean that they want a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output or at least the datatypes

Comment: Not necessarily, because if you use a single wildcard at the end, `'itle%'` won't match `'title'` anymore. Be careful about that, I was just mentioning that it won't use the index.

Comment: but you said the `'title%'` will use the index right? so like this `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE title LIKE 'title%' AND cat_1 = 'cat_1 and so on...'` This will use the index right?

Comment: Yes, however, `'title%'` may not be what you want, if you need to be able to search for any character within the title, this won't work as it will only find things that start with `'title'`

Comment: Hi, I read and searched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an "answer" to your question is a bit complex and your supposition on index use are not always correct.

The shorter answer would be: "It depends".

Actually the use of an index depends by several factor: number of records in table, index structure, field requested, condition in query, statistics.

1) Number of records: if it is small, maybe db engine decide not to use the index (especially if you write SELECT * of SELECT --several columns in table not in index --).

The index could be used (not considering WHERE condition too) if you SELECT only some of or all the columns in index.

2) index structure: as you pointed, it's relevant.   Morevore there are two different main ways an index can be "used": scan and seek.  Seek is the most efficient.  In most cases you have a seek if you look for the columns in the index in the same order you wrote them: eg. SELECT TITLE FROM YOUR TABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE 'ABC%').  Note: if you wrote LIKE '%ABC%' it can't do a seek, but a scan.  (A scan mean that db have to look for the whole index, from the beginning to the end, while with a seek he goes directly to the relevant pages, as you will do looking for a phone number of a person in a phonebook using lastname).

3) Field requested: you should consider that if you write SELECT * (as I pointed above, db engine could decide to use anyway a full table scan)

4) Condition in query.

5) Statistics: db engine write statistics on data and index (number of record, structure,etc).  If they are not updated, it's possibile it use or don't use index in "erroneus" way.

**----- Updated : simple (not exhaustive ... ) demo**

Actually (with this small data, I had to comment your KEY 'title_date_posted' to make it use in some cases the "advanced_query" index: otherwise it seems to try to use that; 
as I told you, db engine makes an internal decisions what index to use).

Test done on rextester.com:

```
##DROP TABLE post_lists;

CREATE TABLE `post_lists` (
 `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `users_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `details` varchar(10000) NULL,
 `cat_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
    , KEY `date_posted` (`date_posted`)
    , KEY `code` (`code`)
    , KEY `users_id_date_posted` (`users_id`,`date_posted`)
    ##, KEY `title_date_posted` (`title`,`date_posted`)
    , KEY `cat_1_date_posted` (`cat_1`,`date_posted`)
)   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE post_lists ADD INDEX advanced_query (`title`, `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3`, `date_posted`);

INSERT INTO post_lists (users_id, code, title, cat_1, cat_3_code, details, cat_2, cat_3) VALUES ('123', 'ABC', 'TITLE1', '001','C3','blah blah blah', '002', '003');
INSERT INTO post_lists (users_id, code, title, cat_1, cat_3_code, details, cat_2, cat_3) VALUES ('456', 'ABC', 'TITLE2', '002','C32','blah blah blah', '0021', '0031');

SELECT * FROM post_lists;

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM post_lists WHERE title = 'TITLE1'; 
EXPLAIN SELECT title FROM post_lists  WHERE title = 'TITLE1'; 
EXPLAIN SELECT title, cat_1, cat_3, code FROM post_lists  WHERE title = 'TITLE1'; 
EXPLAIN SELECT title, cat_1, cat_3 FROM post_lists  WHERE title = 'TITLE1'; 

DROP TABLE post_lists;
```

Output:

```
    +----+----+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------+------------+----------------+-------+-------+
|    | id | users_id | code |     date_posted     |    date_updated     | title  | cat_1 | cat_3_code |    details     | cat_2 | cat_3 |
+----+----+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------+------------+----------------+-------+-------+
|  1 |  1 |      123 | ABC  | 27.06.2017 11:02:16 | 27.06.2017 11:02:16 | TITLE1 |   001 | C3         | blah blah blah |   002 |   003 |
|  2 |  2 |      456 | ABC  | 27.06.2017 11:02:16 | 27.06.2017 11:02:16 | TITLE2 |   002 | C32        | blah blah blah |  0021 |  0031 |
+----+----+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------+------------+----------------+-------+-------+

+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|    | id | select_type |   table    | partitions | type | possible_keys  |      key       | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 |  1 | SIMPLE      | post_lists | NULL       | ref  | advanced_query | advanced_query |     257 | const |    1 |      100 | NULL  |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+



+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|    | id | select_type |   table    | partitions | type | possible_keys  |      key       | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |  1 | SIMPLE      | post_lists | NULL       | ref  | advanced_query | advanced_query |     257 | const |    1 |      100 | Using index |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+

+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|    | id | select_type |   table    | partitions | type | possible_keys  |      key       | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 |  1 | SIMPLE      | post_lists | NULL       | ref  | advanced_query | advanced_query |     257 | const |    1 |      100 | NULL  |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+


+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|    | id | select_type |   table    | partitions | type | possible_keys  |      key       | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |  1 | SIMPLE      | post_lists | NULL       | ref  | advanced_query | advanced_query |     257 | const |    1 |      100 | Using index |
+----+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: If I not use `*` but selected more than half of the total columns will it do full table scan too?

Comment: I only select 3 columns but mysql does not using the index.

Comment: See updated answers (I don't like very much people who removes their vote...)

Comment: yup, I dropped that index.

Comment: Any index has a "cost": pls remember not to add (or remove) index just for a query.  You should carefully consider and study which query users do and how often and what kind of query.

Comment: I suggest to look for a good tutorial (es. Google: SQL INDEX BEST PRACTICES) --> https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9625.best-practices-for-creating-indexes  (this is for MSSQL, but some things are valid for other db)      or MYSQL INDEX BEST PRACTICES --> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135563/better-understand-table-indexing-best-practices

Comment: Hi, I read and searched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted DESC`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?