# Is the query processing fast if I create an index on a column but make a query for multiple column out of which one is the indexed column?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, rdbms

For example, let's say I created index on `'id'` but I make a query like this:

```
select id, class, name from student;
```

Will the query processing be random or will it be optimised according to the id column?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's optimized.
As index is there on id column it will make faster execution of same query.

Comment: Not that query!

Answer (score 0):

With exactly your query it's probable the index will not be used.  It could be different if you add

```
"WHERE ID = somevalue";
```

or if your query is

```
SELECT ID FROM STUDENT;
```

Try to give a read to [How can I index these queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774927/how-can-i-index-these-queries/44775208#44775208)