# Combining two queries and using HAVING

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My solution about this problem is by using 2 queries, but I am wondering if I can do it in one query only.

I have tables like these:

**saved_docs**

```
   id   |   user_id   |   doc_id   |   date   
-----------------------------------------------
   1    |   2         |   1        |   date       
   2    |   3         |   2        |   date       
   3    |   2         |   3        |   date
```

**docs_list**

```
   id   |   url   |   title   |   date   
-----------------------------------------
   1    |   url   |   title   |   date       
   2    |   url   |   title   |   date      
   3    |   url   |   title   |   date
```

What I want is **first** to get the `doc_id` on where the `user_id` is equal to `user's id`. Then, get the **docs** on where the `id` in the **docs_list** is equal to `doc_id`/s I get in **saved_docs** and **order by** the **saved_docs**' `date`.

This can be done on 2 queries, but if there is a possibility that I can do it in one only then I will go for it.

Here is my current **mysql query**:

```
SELECT docs_list.url, docs_list.title

FROM docs_list

INNER JOIN saved_docs

ON saved_posts.user_id = {$user_id}

ORDER BY saved_docs.date DESC
```

Note: I read about `HAVING`, problem is I do not know how to apply it to this query.

Current problem:

It is giving me all the docs in which is obvious because it does not give the right `doc_id`/s (automated). What do I need to do to make this the way I wanted to?

**[SOLVED]**

Note: Both **etsa**'s and **adam**'s answer solved my problem.

Comment: Do try and finish your thought in the title. It helps steer people towards the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT docs_list.url, docs_list.title
FROM docs_list
INNER JOIN saved_docs ON docs_list.id = saved_docs.doc_id
 WHERE saved_posts.user_id = {$user_id}
ORDER BY saved_docs.date DESC
```

Comment: thanks! it solved the problem, but I changed `saved_docs.id` to `saved_docs.doc_id` and it work. Please do change it for anyone out there having a trouble like me.

Comment: Hi, I have a question, what Index/es do I need to make for this query? I currently have an index for `user_id` and `date` in **saved_docs**. Right now mysql using the said index, and the **primary index** in **docs_list** which is the id. Is that enough? or do I need to add more?

Comment: Indexes creation should be studied carefully to obtain desired effects and avoid problems or create useless indexes.   Use Execution Plan to check effects.  It could be an introduction this answer (I did it for MySql, but it generic).  Anyway could be be useful add saved_docs.id to your index (but alway check with Execution plan; SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON could be useful too).

Comment: I forgot the link in the comment before (after the words "this answe"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774927/how-can-i-index-these-queries/44775208#44775208

Comment: what link? first one or the second one?

Comment: I wrote "it could be an introduction to this answer" but I forgot to paste the link I wrote in the second comment.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to do it in the opposite order.

First find all docs saved by user `{$user_id}`, then fetch the info about those docs and sort the list.

```
SELECT docs_list.url, docs_list.title
FROM saved_docs 
LEFT JOIN docs_list
ON docs_list.id = saved_docs.doc_id
WHERE saved_docs.user_id = {$user_id}
ORDER BY saved_docs.date DESC
```

Comment: thanks! +1, but unfortunately I can't accept your answer as there is one who answered it first.

Comment: Thats how it goes :)

Comment: Inner join will be more suitable for this