# Improving MySQL Query-Performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Query in PHP File ([SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/XVDFQ59723))

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies

LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

HAVING find_in_set('$category1', genres_name) $andor find_in_set('$category2', genres_name) 

ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
```

In this query: `$category1` and `$category2` are variables like (Action, Crime, Horror, Comedy etc)

`$andor` is an variable. It's value is `AND`, if both variables `$category1` and `$category2` have values.

If only `$category1` have value, then `$andor` variable value is `OR`

---

Here this 10 querys take around 4-6 seconds to display. My expected speed is less than `0.1` seconds. I have around 80k rows and 35 columns in MySQL tables.

**My Indexes**

```
create index idxm on tmdb_movies(tmdb_id);
create index idxv on videos(videos_tmdb_id, videos_name, videos_key);
create index idxv on genres(tmdb_id, genres_name);
```

**`tmdb_movies` table:**

```
tmdb_id      movie_title
1            Logan
2            Iron Man
3            Superman
```

**`genres` table**

```
tmdb_id                 genres_name
1                         Crime
1                         Comedy
1                         Drama
2                         Action
2                         Horror
2                         Documentary
3                         Music
```

**`videos` table**

```
videos_tmdb_id          videos_name
1                       Official Trailer
1                       Trailer 2 
2                       Trailer 1
2                       Trailer 2 HD
3                       Superman Trailer 1
3                       Superman Trailer 2
```

Let me know, if you need more information

Edit: Explain Query Screeshot

[image]

Comment: Have you run `EXPLAIN` on your query?

Comment: Yes, I'd be curious to see @TimBiegeleisen suggestion too.

Comment: I don't think MySQL can use an index to speed up the `GROUP BY`, but those calls to `FIND_IN_SET()` could be costly.  You might want to normalize your data and avoid making them.

Comment: Edited question, and added Explain query Screenshot. I am using one to many relationship structure. Normalization structure is different? I can change my structure without emptying MySQL tables?

Comment: Then, anyway to replace `GROUP BY` or `Find_IN_SET()` ? Any other query sir?

Comment: Your genre table appears to be a junction table. Is that right? Strange if it is. It's always clearer if you follow the steps set out in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I will create SQL Fiddle, give me 5 minutes

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://rextester.com/XVDFQ59723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with the following query:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies

LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres g WHERE g.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND g.genres_name = '$category1' )

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
```

Note, that I included the condition `1=1` in the `WHERE` clause. This is, so you can easily append `AND whatever`. This way you can more easily build an if condition in your code, to append `$category2` or not. Checking for an empty string like you do is pointless and should be avoided.

EDIT:

To avoid the `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` you'd have to write those as subqueries to avoid multiplication by the join. I didn't do it for the genres, though, cause it's covered pretty well with your index, I think.
Anyway, I also have to say, that I doubt that you will gain any improvement with this.

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(videos_key) FROM videos v WHERE v.videos_tmdb_id = tmdb_movies.tmdb_id)
, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(videos_name) FROM videos v WHERE v.videos_tmdb_id = tmdb_movies.tmdb_id)
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies
JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres g WHERE g.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND g.genres_name = '$category1' )

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
```

Comment: Great, now the page opens in `1.1` seconds. Anyway to further optimize it. And this is how, I put `$category2` also right? http://prntscr.com/ftrdb5

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way, but like I said, I would prefer to only append the condition for category2 with `and` when there's actually a value in $category2. To further improve the query, I think there's not much more you can do query-wise. What does the `EXPLAIN` output say?

Comment: I heard `DISTINCT` can also damage speed, How can I remove it without any bug, like `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` or displaying the same thing multiple times

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the link: Here is explain query Screenshot http://prntscr.com/ftrkj7

Comment: Oh last thing, What you mean by append it? I never heard of it before

Comment: appending like attaching? When you build your query string in your application you can have an if block like in this pseudo code: `if ($category != '') then $where = $where + 'AND whatever'; $query = $select + $from + $where;`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to change (if possible) TEXT datatype with VARCHAR, using effective max length for VARCHAR.  TEXT could have bad effect on index performance. 
It could have little meaning to analyse execution plan with so few records as the ones you put on rextester, so please try on your database and let me know.

Eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE genres (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  genres_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE videos (
  videos_tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  videos_name VARCHAR(800) NOT NULL,
  videos_key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

And then create the index you suggested, but I would give a try changing index on genres to:

```
create index idxv on genres(genres_name, tmdb_id);
```

Comment: What is the difference between `create index idxv on genres(genres_name, tmdb_id);` `create index idxv on genres(tmdb_id,genres_name,);`

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774927/how-can-i-index-these-queries/44775208#44775208

Comment: Basically, it can go directly to records wih genres_name (as you would do looking for a last name in a phone book).  You are filtering records with genres_name, so I can suppose the index in that way could give some benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get the genres first, and then join the rest to that result:

```
SELECT
tmdb_movies.movie_title,
tmdb_movies.tmdb_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name
FROM
(
SELECT
distinct(tmdb_id) as tmdb_id
FROM
genres
WHERE 
genres_name = '$category1' $andor genres_name = '$category2'
) x
LEFT JOIN tmdb_movies ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=x.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=x.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN genres ON genres.tmdb_id=x.tmdb_id
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,x.tmdb_id
ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
```

Comment: It display nothing mate. Test your code here: http://rextester.com/XVDFQ59723

I added SQL fiddle now