# SQLite & MySQL Compound Index vs Single index

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table with two fields: `a,b`
Both fields are indexed separately -- no compound index.

While trying to run a select query with both fields:

`select * from table where a=<sth> and b=<sth>`

It took over 400ms. while

`select * from table where a=<sth>`

took only 30ms;

Do I need set a compound index for `(a,b)`?

Reasonably, if I have indexes on both `a` and `b`, it should be fast for queries of `a AND b` like above right?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select *
from table
where a = <sth> and b = <sth>;
```

The best index is on `table(a, b)`.  This can also be used for your second query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually (but not always).
In your case the number of different values in a (and b) and the number of columns you use in your select can change the way db decide to use index / table.
For example,

if in table you have,say, 100.000 records and 80.000 of them have the same value for a, when you query for:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=<your value>
```

db engine could decide to "scan" directly the table without using the index, while if you query

```
SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE a=<your value>
```

and in index you added column b too (in index directly or with INCLUDE) it's quite probable that db engine will use the index.

Try to give a look on internet for index tips and give a look too to [How can I index these queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774927/how-can-i-index-these-queries/44775208#44775208)

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) explains how index lookups work.

Once the database has used an index to look up some rows, the other index is no longer efficient to use (there is no easy method to filter the results of the first lookup because the other index refers to rows in the original table, not to entries in the first index). See [Multiple AND-Connected WHERE-Clause Terms](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_multiple_and_connected_where_clause_terms).

To make index lookups on two columns as fast as possible, you need [Multi-Column Indices](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_multi_column_indices).

Comment: But this does not explain why first query is much slower than the second query. Also in my scenario, field a is actually unique thus the two queries should take equal time at least given a=<sth> alwasy returns 1 row.

Comment: Might be a caching effect. Edit the question to show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for both queries.