# sql what index structure for multi filter usersearch

Tags: mysql, sql

My users can query data with any combination 0 to 5 filters:

```
id, data, filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5
1, xxx, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, yyy, 5, 6, 6, 3, 52
```

I don't think compound indexes will work since there are too many possible combinations. Are 5 single column indexes on the filter columns my next best option?

UPDATE:

Referring to @GordonLinoff suggestion:

Instead of defining multiple columns for the filters I could add a key value table:

```
data_table_id, key, value
1, filter1, 1
1, filter2, 2
1, filter3, 3
1, filter4, 4
1, filter5, 5
2, filter1, 5
2, filter2, 6
2, filter3, 6
2, filter4, 3
2, filter5, 52
```

However, how would I use the original query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE filter1 > 1 AND filter2 > 5
```

with this new structure?

UPDATE:

Ok here is a solution for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE id IN(
  SELECT result_id FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(result_id) AS matches, result_id FROM filters
    WHERE (key = "gender" AND val = 'm') OR (key = "age" AND val > 30 )
    GROUP by result_id
  ) WHERE matches = 2
)
```

Any objections?

Comment: You should probably have a table called `<something>Filters` with one row per filter for each `id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So I guess something like: `data_table_id, key, value`
I am just wondering how I would query on that structure. E.g. How to intersect the results of 
`Where data_table_id is 1 and key = 'filter1' and value > 10`
and
`Where data_table_id is 1 and key = 'filter2' and value > 5`

Comment: what kind of search do you need to do?  (eg. using id, and/or using only one filter and/or using all the filter together without id, ...).  How many records can you predict?

Comment: I need to find the data_table_ids that fulfill all criteria (i.e. multiple key value pairs). I will update the question to make it more clear

Comment: This is too abstract for me. Is it something like this: You have a product table and users can either select products by product name or by product group or by price or by brand or by any combination of these, and you want to know what index(es) would be appropriate for the products table then?

Comment: "i.e. multiple key value pairs": how many?  How many records can you predict will be in your table ?  Using always AND or using OR too?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes :)

Comment: @etsa It will be in the millions. For now it is only AND conditions. But I might add OR later on

Comment: @Chirs I am curious to see others' answers, but at moment (based on information you post) it seems to me best way is to make five separate indexes (one for each filter), thinking later about adding one other column to each index based on users queries.

Comment: Well, there are many situations where an index might not be used. Your example `WHERE filter1 > 1 AND filter2 > 5` for instance. There may be many records matching `filter1 > 1` and many matching `filter2 > 5`, but only few matching both. Then the DBMS would probably read the whole table and look for those few records, rather than compare two big indexes. Indexes are mainly used for equality where only few records are supposed to match, e.g. `where product name = 'yellow car'`. Sometimes for ranges too, e.g. `where price between 20.00 and 20.50`.

Comment: The idea of using single-column indexes and maybe adding indexes/columns later sounds good.

Comment: @Chris I hope this can help you (see my answer there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774927/how-can-i-index-these-queries/44775208#44775208       Moreover, as pointed by Thorsten, a lot depends by field cardinality / selectivity: e.g, if one of the filter is sex, with M or F value, it's possible that your db will not use that index.  Another factor is what field you have to obtain as a result (just ID or all the column in your original table?)